# Android: Static variable is null inside Adapter

Tags: java, android, static, android-arrayadapter

I have tried every possible question here, but couldnt get around it.

I have a java file(android activity) where I declare

```
private someAdapter someAdapterObj;
```

Inside onCreate() I call the constructor and get the adapter is instantiated.

```
this.someAdapterObj= new someAdapter (this,
                       R.layout.item_row,someAdapter.getAllNews());
```

Inside someAdapter file, I have

```
private static someArrayList;
```

I also have a addtoarraylist() inside someAdapter.

Now, I call the addtoarraylist() from onCreate in the mainActivity, but before I instantiate the adapter. This should be possible because, the arraylist is static. But, I get a nullpointer exception when i add to the arraylist. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Well where do you initialize `someArrayList`? You haven't shown that.

Comment: Could you please add `someAdapter` code?

Comment: @JonSkeet Mann..Thanks a lot.. how did i not see that.. that was exactly the problem. God, am jumping out of the building.. :)

Comment: @AdamSznajder Hi, the answer from JonSkeet helped. thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet You should add your comment as an answer so that the OP can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any instance or static variable whose type is a class (not a primitive) defaults to `null`. You need to initialize it - for example:

```
private static List<Foo> someArrayList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

*However*:

- `ArrayList` is not thread-safe, so you'll need synchronization
- The use of static variables like this is a bit of a code smell (global state); it's usually cleaner if you can hook your components up appropriately so you don't need any global state